# Specify a node type (bundle) in entity reference field

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom entity type which has an entity reference field.

```
   $fields['referenced_article'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Article'))
  ->setDescription(t('The associated article.'))
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'node')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'settings' => array(
      'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
      'size' => 60,
      'placeholder' => '',
    ),
    'weight' => -3,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

This field returns now the nodes of all the node types when finding a match. How can I specify a node type? (I only want to show the nodes of type "article")

Do I need to use a specific setting for selecting content only one node type?

Comment: How can I change this setting per bundle?

Comment: answering myself: https://github.com/barraponto/attendance/blob/development/src/Form/AttendanceTypeForm.php#L101-L109

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding

```
->setSetting('handler_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['article' => 'article']]),
```

[Source](https://www.drupal.org/node/2576151)

Comment: I'm on Drupal 8.5 and by adding this I get no results at all :(

Comment: @hugronaphor you might have to check that you don't have conflicting `setSetting` or `setSettings` calls in the field definition. If you do, only the last one wins.